# SQL Average of a count subset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, average, resultset

Let's say I have an indexed view that is bucketing the number of days people stay at a hotel in a given month. When creating a report I want to insert a row into my result set that shows the average number of days for all months.

My indexed view looks like this:

```
NumMonth | NumPeople | NumDays
1        | 4         | 3
1        | 4         | 4
2        | 1         | 9
3        | 3         | 6
3        | 2         | 10
```

How can I select the average length of stay in a single line?

My current query looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO @results(month1, month2, month3, quarter1)
SELECT 
   'month1' = ISNULL(CASE WHEN v.NumMonth = 1
         THEN convert(decimal(10,3), sum(v.NumPeople * v.NumDays)) / convert(decimal(10,3), sum(v.NumPeople)) 
         ELSE null END, 0),
   'month2' = ISNULL(CASE WHEN v.NumMonth = 2
         THEN convert(decimal(10,3), sum(v.NumPeople * v.NumDays)) / convert(decimal(10,3), sum(v.NumPeople)) 
         ELSE null END, 0),
   'month3' = ISNULL(CASE WHEN v.NumMonth = 3
         THEN convert(decimal(10,3), sum(v.NumPeople * v.NumDays)) / convert(decimal(10,3), sum(v.NumPeople)) 
         ELSE null END, 0),
   'quarter1' = ISNULL(CASE WHEN v.NumMonth = 1 OR v.NumMonth = 2 OR v.NumMonth = 3
         THEN convert(decimal(10,3), sum(v.NumPeople * v.NumDays)) / convert(decimal(10,3), sum(v.NumPeople)) 
         ELSE null END, 0)
FROM MonthTotalsView v with(noexpand)
```

I am getting the error that the select list is invalid because my NumMonth is not aggregated or grouped. But I want it all in a single line, not broken out by month. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The results I'm looking for are the following:

```
month1 | month2 | month3 | quarter1
2.5    | 9      | 7.6    | 5.357
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide the results you want.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using SSMS 2016

Answer (score 0):

> How can I select the average length of stay in a single line?

Assuming your data represents one row per stay:

```
select avg(numdays)
from MonthTotalsView;
```

If you want this per month:

```
select nummonth, avg(numdays)
from MonthTotalsView
group by nummonth;
```

Comment: I have updated my question to show what I am looking for. Thank you.